# How to install log4jdbc on solr

Tags: log4j, solr, jetty

What is the procedure for installing log4jdbc into Solr?

http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to answer this one, so, one would put this into their dataConfig.xml (or whatever, you name it)